# MAMP with MySQL natural driver

Tags: php, mamp, mysqlnd

So I've been working with MAMP to develop a site locally on my computer, but one of the things that has been really bugging me is that MAMP doesn't come with the MySQL Natural Driver for PHP. So I can't use the lovely `get_result()` function. I even tried compiling PHP manually with the driver, but that quickly went up in flames. If it is impossible to set MAMP up with the mysqlnd, then could someone explain what would be the best way to go about getting it? Running Mac OS X 10.7 Lion.

Comment: Having same issue now, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @WilliamHand This is from awhile ago, but I believe I didn't and just changed how I did everything. Sorry I can't give you more information. One thing I would suggest though is just setting up a normal Apache/PHP/MySQL server on your computer as opposed to going through MAMP, it is a lot easier to use.

Comment: this will probably never work well...switch to pdo or a different lamp stack instead

Comment: I can recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install the software you want to use. I personally prefer a [Nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main)/[PHP-FPM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)/[MariaDB](https://mariadb.org) setup, but you can go with Apache/MySQL too. I'm not familiar with how MAMP handles configuration, but using Homebrew _will_ require you to dive into it yourself (although it isn't hard and has sane defaults).

Comment: Not what are you looking for, but I reccomend using Vagrant+Puppet to have a clean virtual machine do the setup for you. To configure Vagrant for php developement, you can use the fantastic tool [phpuppet](https://puphpet.com/). Just follow the wizard, download the ZIP file, unzip it ant then vagrant up on the directory (you need vagrant and virtual box installed, of course).

Comment: @Mtorres: You might want to check [Phansible](http://phansible.com/). Same idea as PuPHPet, but uses [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/) in stead of Puppet for provisioning.

Comment: @EdGeorge I am not sure if StackOverflow is the best place to ask this question. You might get an answer on ServerFault, since they do more with configuration kind-of-stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is most likely the best solution for conflicting issues with PHP, MySQL and etc. While many people are timid at configuring their own virtual machine you can use a preconfigured box like the one listed here:

http://laravel.com/docs/homestead

This allows you to get up and running quickly and modify MySQL anyway you prefer.